# Is there any app for voice recording on Ubuntu Touch phone?

Tags: software-recommendation, application-development, ubuntu-touch

I am working on **voice over sensor networks** project.For this I need to give the voice data to the network by ubuntu touch phone(Nexus 4) through datacable.Can anybody suggest any app for my project???

Answer (score 1):

There are no [core-apps](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone-coreapps/) for this yet. And I havent seen any user developed apps for voice recording yet. I don't know if there are libraries to support this at the present.

Are you restricted to using Ubuntu Touch? It's still a fairly young system with a small but dedicated community. Perhaps Android with its much larger community can provide you with what you're after.

Comment: Actually I am new to ubuntu touch app development......but I am interested in developing that app in touch.Can you just help me in getting the QML code of **CALL** function of ubuntu touch....so that later I can modify the code suitable to my project.....thanks in advance